# getJSON not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a really small jquery program that is trying to get the the value fom a key. The JSON file looks like this:

```
{
    "Key1": [
        "http://google.com",
        "http://github.com",
        "http://codepen.com"
    ],
    "Key2": [
        "http://google.com",
        "http://github.com",
        "http://codepen.com"
    ],
    "Key3": [
       "http://google.com",
       "http://github.com",
       "http://codepen.com"
    ]
}
```

I want to key the value based on key, and then have an iframe rotate through them. The code seems to be right, but when I load the page, nothing happens. I have added console.log to see it step into the program, and it stops at the getJSON function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  console.log("What");
    $.getJSON('url_dict.json', function(json) { 
    console.log(json)        
        $.each(json, function(key, value) {
            if (key == "Key1") {
                console.log(value);
                locos = value;
                console.log(locos);
                console.log(locos.length);
            }
        });
        var len = locos.length;
        var iframe = $('#frame');
        var i = 0;
        setInterval(function () {
            $(iframe).attr('src', locos[++i % len]);
        }, 5000);
   });
});
```

I am not quite sure what the issue is. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Can you load the `'url_dict.json'` file directly, e.g. by pasting its URL in your browser?

Comment: My best guess is that `url_dict.json` is not valid JSON.  Do you not get an error in the console?

Comment: BTW, that `$.each` loop can be replaced with `locos = json.Key1;`.

Comment: you'll need to make sure you are hosting the above code in some webserver (IIS, apache) if you are just opening an HTML file it cannot access other files.

Comment: Google doesn't allow its site to be ran in an iframe.  You should see an error in your console about that.

Comment: Ran the url_dict.json thru json lint. It looks right. I agree with @ChristianTernus

Comment: @abc123 it is hosted in a nginx server, if I create a function to read the json with passing the value to another function, I can append the value to the console | Explosion Pills the JSON is valid, no errors, checked with jsonlint | Rocket Hazmat, just a place holder for the real urls, these ones you see aren't the real ones | Christian Ternus it works if passed directly

Comment: add the .fail method and return to us with the results. `.getJSON('url_dict.json', function(json) { ...}).fail(function(){console.log(arguments)})`

Comment: @Kevin B parse error `[Object { readyState=4, responseText="{\n "Key1": [\n ...1.flipkey.net"\n ]\n}\n", status=200, more...}, "parsererror",
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character
 

...elem,e)),a=1,u=20;if(s&&s[3]!==o){o=o||s[3],i=i||[],s=+r||1;do a=a||".5",s/=a,x....

]`

Comment: That means your json is likely invalid, but since you only gave us a small sample of it, we can't be sure. You say it is valid, but jQuery says it isn't. it must not be valid.